# How can this equation hold $$\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |u(m,n)|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1} |v(k,l)|^2$$?

Tags: image-processing, transform

I am trying to learn digital Image processing by myself and now stuck at a problem in the two dimensional unitary transformations. It states that let $U$ be the input image and $V$ be the transformed image and $A$ is the unitary transformation matrix.
To prove above equation I am rather trying to prove $$U^2=V^2$$ which I think is equivalent to proving equation in question.We have $$ V=A U A^T $$ now to prove the above relation: $$V^2=V^{*T} V$$ where 
 $$ V=A U A^T \mbox{ and } V^{*T}=A^*[A^*U^*]^T$$ which on solving gives me $$ A^* U^{*T} U A^T $$ which gives $$ A^* U^2 A^T $$but it should be equal to $$U^2$$, as I understand. Though $$ A^T A^*=I $$ as $A$ is Unitary matrix, but as much as I know we can't change order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this using trace of the matrix and the similarity invariance property:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{N-1} \left| v(k,l) \right|^2 &=  \text{tr} \left(V^{*} V\right) \\
&= \text{tr} \left(A U^{*} A^{*} A U A^{*} \right) \\
&= \text{tr} \left(A U^{*} U A^{*} \right) \\
&= \text{tr} \left(U^{*} U \right)~~\text{See attached image} \\
&= \sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \left| u(m,n) \right|^2
\end{align}

The following snapshot has been taken from wikipedia:- [Trace of a Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra))

[image: Image copied from Wikipedia]

Comment: Thanks a lot!      just one thing, I hope you mean to say first equation is equal to$$ tr(V^{*T}V)$$

Comment: Actually $*$ includes transpose. Look at complex conjugate of a matrix.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't interpreted the question that way. Good work @user3288586 !

Answer (score 2):

OK, so let's have a look at whether

$$\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |u(m,n)|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1} |v(k,l)|^2\tag{1}$$

is equivalent to

$$U^2=V^2\tag{2}$$

Let's have a look at a simple $2 \times 2$ example:
$$
U = \left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
u_a & u_b\\
u_c & u_d
\end{array}
\right ] \\
V = \left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
v_a & v_b\\
v_c & v_d
\end{array}
\right ]
$$
so that
$$
U^2 = \left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
u_a & u_b\\
u_c & u_d
\end{array}
\right ]
\left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
u_a & u_b\\
u_c & u_d
\end{array}
\right ] = \left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
u_a^2 + u_b u_c & u_au_b + u_bu_d\\
u_cu_a + u_d u_c & u_c u_b + u_d^2
\end{array}
\right ]
$$
and
$$
V^2 = \left [ 
\begin{array}{cc}
v_a^2 + v_b v_c & v_av_b + v_bv_d\\
v_cv_a + v_d v_c & v_c v_b + v_d^2
\end{array}
\right ]
$$

Then (1) becomes
$$
|u_a|^2 + |u_b|^2 + |u_c|^2 + |u_d|^2 =
|v_a|^2 + |v_b|^2 + |v_c|^2 + |v_d|^2 
$$

The two are completely different.  Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: i wonder if Ankit means that $V$ this the result of applying a unity-gain linear transform, e.g. the DFT (with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ scaler in both directions), to the vector $U$.  would that mean that $|V|^2 \ = |U|^2$ ?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : Could be!  But $U$ and $V$ are explicitly called images... so they can't really be vectors, unless they're doing the Matlab `U(:)` operation...

Comment: yeah, so the unitary 2-dim DFT has a $\frac1N$ in both directions.  if it were that linear transform, i think then the energy of the output is the same as the energy of the input.

Comment: Yup. That'd be Parseval, which would make sense.... Hmmm. Let me see if I can rejig the question to ask that.

Comment: Nope. My brain is fried for the day.  Will have a look later, if I can.